# Black screen after installing mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft isn't working and just gives a black screen. My wifi is working, so that's not it. I've tried running it over and over again, but it's a black screen every time. I've only installed Rei's Minimap, and Minecraft worked before that.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with one of your mods, I've had this happen before.  Try redownloading Minecraft.

Comment: You really should provide more details. Did Minecraft work before? What mods did you install?

Comment: i only downloaded 'rei's minimap and yes, minecraft did work before

Comment: Strange, I've never had a problem with Rei's.  Sometimes mods get messed up though, and do that, try redownloading minecraft and then add the mod again.

Comment: You have to be careful installing Rei's though, unless you use a modloader

Answer (score 4):

A black screen after installing mods is usually caused by forgetting to delete the META-INF folder from the jar. Modded Minecraft will not run so long as that folder is still present in the jar.

Reopen the jar file, find that folder and delete it. So long as the mods are for the right version of Minecraft, it should run now.